# How to clear all the automated actions at the end of a script?

Tags: android, python, appium

I'm currently trying to do automate mobile testing and am wondering if there is any way that I can clear all the performed actions after reaching the end of a script execution.
For example, if I automate setting an alarm on Alarm app, can I undo this action at the end of the script?

I am using Python with Appium. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but appium won't do it for you. 
Appium includes some methods called TearDown, After, AfterAll... (depends on the version you are using) that let you do actions after the test is finished.
For example, you can have something like:

```
def setup(self):
    //Code that starts the test
def test_sample():
    // The test itself
def tearDown(self):
    //All the actions that you want to do AFTER the test
```

What i mean by "Appium won't do it for you" is that there is no way to "undo" the actions by itself. You will have to implement all the actions that will undo the changes of the test.